# how we get oauth_refresh_tokens id from user refresh token payload

Tags: laravel, token, laravel-passport

I have upgrade laravel 5 to 9 and only refresh token of laravel passport is not validating ,
so I'm trying to get user id/ oauth_refresh_tokens table ID from user refresh token payload
is there any way to get oauth_refresh_tokens ID from refresh token

I have tried
this [How to get id from refresh token in Laravel Passport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63597859/how-to-get-id-from-refresh-token-in-laravel-passport)
but it throw exception

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.